# Chain of responsibility pattern - tight coupling with descendants

Tags: java, oop

I came to problem how to put the actions into a chain with possibility to pass additional parameters during processing of a action.

Let's consider simple chain of a processes. Input is an object representing an image.
First image is resized, then deployed to ftp and saved to db.
Using a chain of responsibility pattern, calling could look like this:

```
ImageProcessor p = new ImageResizer(desiredSize);
p.setNext(new (new ImageDeployer(ftpServer, path)));
p.setNext(new (new ImageDbSaver(dbConnection, table)));
p.process(image);
p.close();
```

This is working perfectly for one image. 
I would like to process images in a loop and set desiredSize and path there.
I cannot create and close connections every time, so code has to be spread:

```
ImageProcessor p = new ImageResizer();
p.setNext(new (new ImageDeployer(ftpServer)));
p.setNext(new (new ImageDbSaver(dbConnection, table)));

for(Image image : images) {
  p.process(image, size, path);
}
p.close();
```

A problem of the solution is that the ImageProcessor shouldn't know about a size and a path. In case when is used only the ImageDbSaver parameters like size and path doesn't make sense.
What is a better way how to do it?

Comment: Store those values in `ImageResizer` class implementation. Note that these values can be loaded from a properties file or another data source.

Comment: Store values in ImageResizer doesn't give a such benefit. For example, you will have two class properties bigSize and smallSize.
But you still need to make a decision which size to use p.process(image, ImageResizer.smallSize, path);

Comment: Well, the `ImageProcessor` doesn't need to know a size as well, just the `ImageResizer` because that's its job: **resize** images. It can have a default value like `smallSize` but if you want to change it you could pass an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most robust solution in your case it so add some kind of processing context.

In simplest case, you can (1) use, for example `Map<String, Object>` for this, (2) pack it with arguments specific for various processors, (3) pass it into `p.process(...)` and (4) then extract, for example `size` in the processor that resizes the image.

This way you'll get flexibility to add new arguments without need to change signature of `ImageProcessor` and keeping implementers decoupled form one another.

The real world example of something similar would be request\session\servlet contexts in Java EE. You can put stuff into them on various lifecycle stages (for example security configuration options about what urls should require auth) and then fetch this stuff where needed (for example in [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to block\allow access to resource based on auth requirements).

**UPDATE**

Updating the answer with code example to demonstrate the idea.

So, somewhere in your code you have place where you build your processor chain:

```
ImageProcessor p = new ImageResizer(desiredSize);
p.setNext(new (new ImageDeployer(ftpServer, path)));
p.setNext(new (new ImageDbSaver(dbConnection, table)));
```

In (possibly) other place you create and configure your processing context (it is not really required to configure all processors in one place):

```
Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
context.put("image_width", new Integer(640));
```

In another place in your code you do your processing, passing context to it (I reuse context for all processings  but you might use different contexts for every image):

```
for(Image image : images) {
  p.process(image, context);
}
p.close();
```

Now, somewhere in your `ImageResizer`:

```
@Override
void process(Image image, Map<String, Object> context) {

    // ...

    Integer imageWidth = (Integer) context.get("image_width");

    // ...

}
```

So, context is a common place that helps to deliver data to specific processors, abstracting the details about this data and thus decoupling specific processors from one another.

Comment: It seems that it could work... I like it. Code could look like this:  
`ImageProcessor p = new ImageResizer();  
p.setNext(new (new ImageDeployer(ftpServer)));  
p.setNext(new (new ImageDbSaver(dbConnection, table)));  

for(Image image : images) {  
  p.process(image, new Object[] { new ImageResizerContext(desiredSize), new ImageDeployerContext(path) });
}  
p.close();`  
Then every descendant of ImageProcessor could take its specific Context from array (I used array insted of Map for simplification).

Comment: You've got the core idea right, however, seems that you've misunderstood what I meant by context here. I'll craft code example to show my idea and update answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply store all processors into variables and then chain them.

```
ImageResizer resizer = new ImageResizer();
ImageDeployer deployer = new ImageDeployer(ftpServer);
ImageDbSaver saver = new ImageDbSaver(dbConnection, table);

resizer.setNext(deployer).setNext(saver);

for(Image image : images) {
    deployer.setPath(somePath);
    resizer.setDesiredSize(desiredSize);
    resizer.process(image);
}

resizer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of solving it would be to construct the invariants outside your loop. For example:

```
ImageDeployer deployer = new ImageDeployer(ftpServer);
ImageDbSaver dbSaver = new ImageDbSaver(dbConnection, );

for(Image image : images) {
  ImageProcessor p = new ImageResizer(desiredSize);
  p.setNext(deployer);
  p.setNext(dbSaver);
  p.process(image);
}
dbSaver.close();
deployer.close();
```

If ImageResizer needs to be closed you'll need some way of detaching things in the loop.

Comment: It's not the better solution because also the path can change inside of the loop (e.g. depending on type of image). So closing connection every time is not optimal ...

Comment: You can initialise everything that might get used outside the loop. You only need to couple them together in the loop, and close everything only when the whole loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

How would you code this if performance was not a problem? I think constructing a custom  processor chain for every image would be a good solution then because you seem to have different values for every image.

Now if it turns out that this is too slow (which certainly can happen), why not pass a `DatabaseConnection` and `FtpConnection` object (which are initialized outside the loop) to the processors that need these?

Comment: When reading the code I thought I could safely assume that the connections are already created and kept open until `p.close()` is called.